# Types of services for long running asp.net processes

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Our website has a long running calculation process which keeps the client waiting for a few minutes until it's finished. We've decided we need a design change, and to farm out the processing to a windows or a WCF service, while the client is presented with another page, while we're doing all the calculations.

What's the best way of implementing the service though?

We've looked at background worker processes, but it looks like these are problematic because if IIS can periodically shut down threads

It seems the best thing to use is either a Windows service or a WCF service. Does anyone have a view on which is better for this purpose?
If we host the service on another machine, would it have to be a WCF service?
It looks like it's difficult to have the service (whatever type it is) to communicate back to the website - maybe instead the service can update its results to a database, and the website polls that for the required results later on.

It's an open ended question I know, but does anyone have any ideas?

thanks

Comment: http://hangfire.io/ looks promising-- it's essentially a lightweight message queue. I'm not sure about your distinction between Windows Service & WCF service. A windows service can host a WCF service. Or a windows service can host ad-hoc what ever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the true gain in terms of performance will come from the design change.

If I were to chose between windows service and WCF I would go with the Windows service because I would be able to fix an affinity and prioritize as I want. However I will have to implement the logic for serving multiple clients in the same time (which in a WCF service approach will be handled by IIS).

So in terms of performance if you use .NET framework for both the WCF service and Windows service the performance difference will not be major. **Windows service would be more "controllable", WCF would be more straight-forward and with no big performance penalties.**

For these types of tasks I would focus on highly optimizing the single thread calculation. If you have a complex calculation, can it be written in native code (C or C++)? You could make a .DLL file that is highly optimized and is used by either the Windows service or the WCF service. Using this approach will allow you to select best compiler option and make best use of your machine resources. Also nothing stops you from creating multiple threads in the .DLL function.

The link between the website and the service can be ensured in both cases: through sockets for Windows service (extra code for creating the protocol) or directly through SOAP for the WCF. If you push the results in a database the difficulty would be letting the website **(and knowing to wich particular user session)** know that the data is there.

So that's what I would do.

Hope it helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for that - the calculations are not that difficult, but they involve calling external web services as well, which is why I think WCF might be the way to go (can a pure windows service easily call an external webservice?)

Comment: The pure native windows service can call an external web service but you need to generate the appropriate code for implementing the communication protocol. I don't think the effort will pay off in terms of performance. WCF is probably best solution.

Comment: Also your problem seems to be the latency of the web services not the fact that the computation threads don't get sufficient priority. Usually in this case better hardware with improved I/O capabilities solves some problems. Another exotic and elegant approach would be using a memcached approach (http://memcached.org/)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is:

- The Client submits the calculation request using a Call to a WCF Service (can be hosted in IIS)
- The calculation request is stored in a database With a unique ID
- The ID is returned to the Client
- A Windows Service (or serveral on several different machines) poll the database for New requests
- The Windows service performs the calculation and stores the result to a result table With the ID
- The Client polls the result table (using a WCF service) With the ID
- When the calculation is finished the result is returned to the client

Comment: Hi Shiraz - good call, that's roughly what we've decided to do. I'm not sure if I made it clear about the calculations - as well as processing stuff, they also involve calling external webserivces - so we want our client to carry on using the website while all these webservice calls & calcs are churning away, but I agree that it's easier for the website to poll the db to see if the calcs have finished, because 'calling back' to the website is very difficult to do. Thanks for your help so far!